# OpenCV: How Do I split an Image?

Tags: opencv

I would like to split an image which is captured from a webcam into N*N squares, so that I can process those squares separably.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a ROI (Region Of Interest) option of OpenCV image structures.
In C interface you need a function [cvSetImageROI](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#setimageroi), in C++ it will be [operator()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id4) of `cv::Mat` class. Here is a simple C++ sample for processing image by NxN blocks:

```
cv::Mat img;
capture >> img;

for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; r += N)
    for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; c += N)
    {
        cv::Mat tile = img(cv::Range(r, min(r + N, img.rows)),
                     cv::Range(c, min(c + N, img.cols)));//no data copying here
        //cv::Mat tileCopy = img(cv::Range(r, min(r + N, img.rows)),
                     //cv::Range(c, min(c + N, img.cols))).clone();//with data copying

        //tile can be smaller than NxN if image size is not a factor of N
        your_function_processTile(tile);
    }
```

C version:

```
IplImage* img;
CvRect roi;
CvSize size;
int r, c;

size = cvGetSize(img);
for (r = 0; r < size.height; r += N)
    for (c = 0; c < size.width; c += N)
    {
        roi.x = c;
        roi.y = r;
        roi.width = (c + N > size.width) ? (size.width - c) : N;
        roi.height = (r + N > size.height) ? (size.height - r) : N;

        cvSetImageROI(img, roi);

        processTile(img);
    }
cvResetImageROI(img);
```

Comment: Yes, cvSetImageROI is for IplImage.

Comment: If I've an IplImage, How Can I use the cv::Mat with the above code?

Comment: [cvarrToMat](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cvarrtomat) can do the conversion.

Comment: Thanks,But how do I access then cvMat tile, I would like to access its row, columns, so that I can play with those tiles...

Comment: There are a lot of methods... I think you'd better read a couple of OpenCV tutorials before continuing. I recommend to try first two from [this page](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/table_of_content_core/table_of_content_core.html)

Comment: I tried tile.row(x).col(x); that doesn't work...
I actually would like for example to draw a black tile in the region (0,4) in the N*N tiles.

Comment: `img(cv::Range(0, N), cv::Range(4*N, 5*N)).setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0))` but you'd better ask a new question since it is different from the current topic.

Comment: Just a note that the inverse of the ROI () operator doesn't seem to work. That is, `result(rowRange, colRange) = modifiedTile;` doesn't do anything. Instead, one must use `modifiedTile.copyTo(result(rowRange, colRange));`